# How to use IntentDonationManager.donate(intent:)

Tags: swift, sirishortcuts, appintents

I just use code like this

```
IntentDonationManager.shared.donate(intent: AddRopeShortcut())
```

And intent never appear neither in spotlight nor Siri widget nor Notification Center